# LCD monitor: resolution vs screen size

Tags: display, resolution

I am having bit of confusion about resolution vs screen size. Say, I have a 20" monitor and a 30" monitor both having 1920X1080. Does this mean that both have an equal number of pixels which intern mean that in 20" monitor, pixels are more closely packed than in 30" monitor?

So, if I am buying a bigger (in size) monitor, should I look for higher resolution?

Comment: Yes, and IMO a 30" that is only 1080P is a TV, not a computer monitor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is correct. A smaller monitor with the same resolution has a higher dot pitch.

Not necessarily. It depends on what you want the larger monitor for. If it's for vision problems then an equal or lower resolution may be preferred.

Comment: Replace "higher dot pitch" with "better dot pitch", since the number used to represent it is actually smaller. And as a side note, if you're really looking at a larger monitor because of vision problems, consider a low-end HDTV (the cheapest you can find that supports 1080p), as those have decent bang for buck these days.